# How do I move some modifications from a feature branch into the main one?

Tags: git, git-branch

As title. I have created a branch to do specific tasks `add-ui-components`. Unfortunately, I also found some specific changes, let's call it `upgrade-webpack-config`, that I want to move out of the current branch. The latter one I just named is a fake branch, as I have neither created a branch for it nor committed those changes. Given that I'm at the branch `add-ui-components` Is it possible that I can move those unstaged file changes back to the `main` so that I can create another branch for it after I'm done with the current branch `add-ui-components`? Thanks

Let me use some graph for better understanding

Input

```
main: A-B-C
feat: A-B-C-D-E + (not related unstaged changes)
```

Expected Output:

```
main: A-B-C + (not related unstaged changes)
feat: A-B-C-D-E + (new related changes added here)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- from the `feat` branch: stash your changes: `git stash --include-untracked`
- go to main: `git checkout main`
- apply the stash: `git stash pop`
- commit `git commit -m "not related unstaged changes"`
- go back to your branch: `git checkout feat`

as the final step, you'll have to merge the "recent changes" in `main` to `feat` - either with a [merge or a rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).

eg, for rebase: `git rebase main` -> this will kinda revert all your commits and apply them one by one as if you had branched `feat` after the "not related unstages changes" commit was applied to `main`

Comment: While I already understood the idea of "rebase". I expect your answer will be very helpful for people who haven't learned the concept. Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 2):

Just do `git switch main`, the unstaged changes will float over.

Unless of course the changed files are different between main/C and feat/E, but then git will tell you so.

In that case you would do a `git stash`, then `git switch main` and then `git stash pop`.

If the latter brings conflicts, you can resolve them and after you verified everything is proper can `git stash drop` the stash entry, because if there were conflicts, `git stash pop` behaves like `git stash apply`, leaving the changes on the stash in case you applied them to the wrong place or need to start over.